# Why do the stripes only appear on legend and not on plot itself?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpattern

Trying to use ggpattern for this plot but can't get it to work right. Legend looks okay doesn't translate to what's on plot itself. Not stripes or dots on actual plot?

```
test <- tibble(names = c("fred", "harry", "tom"),
               start = c(1, 3, 5),
               end = c(10, 5, 7),
               stripe = c("yes", "no", "yes"))

ggplot() +
  geom_rect_pattern(data = test,
            aes(xmin = names,
                xmax = names,
                ymin = start,
                ymax = end,
                color = names,
                fill = names,
                pattern = stripe), size = 4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce the plot without altering your data, you could try:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_rect_pattern(data = test,
                    aes(xmin = as.numeric(factor(names)) - 0.25,
                        xmax = as.numeric(factor(names)) + 0.25,
                        ymin = start,
                        ymax = end,
                        fill = names,
                        pattern = stripe), pattern_fill = 'black', size = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(length(levels(factor(test$names)))),
                     labels = levels(factor(test$names))) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c('none', 'stripe'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you do not have `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` values. Since you use rectangles (you need to specify 4 corners): e.g:

```
plot_df <- data.frame(
  xmin    = c(0, 10, 3),
  xmax    = c(8, 18, 4),
  ymin    = c(0, 10, 8),
  ymax    = c(5, 19, 15),
  type    = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  colour1 = c('red', 'black', 'blue')
)
```

After that

```
ggplot(plot_df) +
  geom_rect_pattern(
    aes(
      xmin=xmin, ymin=ymin, xmax=xmax, ymax=ymax,
      pattern_fill  = I(colour)
    ),
    pattern         = 'stripe',
    colour          = 'black',
    pattern_density = 0.3,
    fill = NA
  ) +
  theme_bw(18)
```

[image: p]